# Circuit breaker on http client can't close back after failure

Tags: akka, akka-http, circuit-breaker

An example of circuit breaker over akka http client that looks totally simple doesn't work expected for me.

```
object HttpWithCircuitBreaker extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
  val breaker =
    new CircuitBreaker(
      system.scheduler,
      maxFailures = 2,
      callTimeout = 3.seconds,
      resetTimeout = 25.seconds)
      .onOpen(println("circuit breaker opened"))
      .onClose(println("circuit breaker closed"))
      .onHalfOpen(println("circuit breaker half-open"))
  while (true) {
    val futureResponse: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new"))
    breaker.withCircuitBreaker(futureResponse).map(resp => resp.status match {
      case Success(_) =>
        resp.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.ignore)
        println("http success")
      case _ =>
        resp.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.ignore)
        println(s"http error ${resp.status.intValue()}")
    }).recover {
      case e@_ =>
        println(s"exception ${e.getMessage}")
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000)
  }
}
```

It starts perfectly fine fetching random numbers. It opens when disconnect from the net but never close back when I reconnect. As you can see from the log there is an attempt to recover but it fails with timeout:

```
http success
http success
http success
exception Tcp command [Connect(www.random.org:443,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed
exception Circuit Breaker Timed out.
circuit breaker opened
exception Tcp command [Connect(www.random.org:443,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker Timed out.
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
circuit breaker half-open             <--- new http call should start here
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker Timed out.  <--- but it fails with timeout
circuit breaker opened
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
exception Circuit Breaker is open; calls are failing fast
```

Gut feeling says that it must be something unconsumed http entity but still I'm not able to make it right.

[Here is the sample on github to play with](https://github.com/kharole/akka-http-circuit-breaker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the circuit breaker to work properly, this `val`

```
val futureResponse: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(...)
```

should be a `def`

```
def futureResponse: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(...)
```

The circuit breaker needs to wrap the asynchronous call - and if you use a `val`, your asynchronous call will start outside the breaker.

Adding to that: refrain from using Thread.sleep in your code, try using - e.g. - Akka [after](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/futures.html#After).

Comment: Thanks. Have finally figured that out that was about.